# Merging multiple excel files into one but getting one extra column

Tags: python, pandas, merge, openpyxl

I have written following code to merge multiple excel files. But in the merged file, it is adding extra column at column A. I do not want that initially being added by the code. What to do if I do not want that extra column while merging the excel files.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
input_file_path="C:/Users/HP/.spyder-py3/New folder/"
output_file_path="C:/Users/HP/.spyder-py3/New folder/"
excel_file_list=os.listdir(input_file_path) #Loading excel files in the code
print(excel_file_list) #names of the files in the input_file_path
dataframe=pd.DataFrame() #Creating a database for merged data
for excel_files in excel_file_list:
    if excel_files.endswith(".xlsx"):
        new_dataframe=pd.read_excel(input_file_path+excel_files)
        dataframe=dataframe.append(new_dataframe)
dataframe.to_excel(output_file_path+"Merged.xlsx")
```

Comment: Try `dataframe.to_excel(output_file_path+"Merged.xlsx", index=False)`

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code might be that the "append" method is concatenating the data of each file along with the index column of each file, which is creating a new index column in the merged file. To avoid this, you can reset the index of each file to default index (0, 1, 2...) before appending it to the merged dataframe. Try to update your code like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
input_file_path="C:/Users/HP/.spyder-py3/New folder/"
output_file_path="C:/Users/HP/.spyder-py3/New folder/"
excel_file_list=os.listdir(input_file_path) #Loading excel files in the code
print(excel_file_list) #names of the files in the input_file_path
dataframe=pd.DataFrame() #Creating a database for merged data
for excel_files in excel_file_list:
    if excel_files.endswith(".xlsx"):
        new_dataframe=pd.read_excel(input_file_path+excel_files)
        new_dataframe = new_dataframe.reset_index(drop=True) # reset index to default (0, 1, 2...)
        dataframe=dataframe.append(new_dataframe)
dataframe.to_excel(output_file_path+"Merged.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the additional column is the index column. Replacing `dataframe.to_excel(output_file_path+"Merged.xlsx")` by `dataframe.to_excel(output_file_path+"Merged.xlsx", index=False)` should solve the issue.